# Can't echo in lmy php form

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

support : Ubuntu, Phpstorm.

I'm extracting data from a text file, using regex, and then i want to input my $match_gsm[n] (result of regex) into my php form like this :

```
$form_souscription->add('Text', 'num_gsm')
              ->label('Num du GSM ')
              ->value('<?php echo $match_gsm[2]; ?>');
```

The problem is that my $match_gsm[2] is defined in another php file, so when i execute this piece of code, i get my php command into the field... instead of having the value contained in that variable.

When using an : `include 'file_upload.php';

I still get the same output in my form field.

Hope i'm dumb and the answer is obvious,

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Stelio Kontos.

Comment: you are writing `php` code within `php code`? it should be written directly without tag

Comment: I agree with @Riad. Does it work with ->value($match_gsm[2]); ?

Comment: a php inception.. code inside a code

Comment: Yeah this is some kind of inception, but nope, it doesn't work with ->value($match_gsm[2]) , even with my include of the file containing this variable... Phpstorm says : Undefined variable 'match_gsm'.

Is it due to my include ? Because in my "file_upload.php ", I don't have the error message regarding match_gsm variable...

Comment: Edit (more than 5 mins after comment...) : Phpstorm says : Undefined variable 'match_gsm'.Is it due to my include ? Because in my "file_upload.php ", I don't have the error message regarding match_gsm variable...Do I have to recreate my variable due to my :  `code`header('Location: form_souscription.php'); `code`     ?

Comment: A solution consists in copy-paste my php form into my "file_upload.php" class... It ain't pretty, I know, but it works !